# How to Change Geometry Nodes Modifier for selected object with Python?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I need to automate this basic task with python, changing the geometry nodes modifier as seen in the screenshot from "GeometryNodes" to "Animation".
My knowledge in Python is 0 could someone help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### A function to change node group of GeometryNodes modifier in all selected object

It will add new Geometry Nodes modifier if not exist

```
import bpy

def change_GN_node_group(node_name):
    selected_objs   = bpy.context.selected_objects
    if node_name in bpy.data.node_groups:
        node_group  = bpy.data.node_groups[node_name]
    else:
        print(f"Node Group {node_name} does not exist")
        return

    for obj in selected_objs:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            md_node = None

            for md in obj.modifiers:    # find GeometryNodes modifier
                if md.type == 'NODES':
                    md_node = md
                    break
            
            if md_node is None: # can not find GeometryNodes modifier, add new one
                md_node = obj.modifiers.new(type='NODES', name="GeometryNodes")

            md_node.node_group = node_group

change_GN_node_group("Animation")
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly!